# SQL How to capitalize only one word

Tags: sql-server, uppercase

I'm looking to capitalize the first word in a string. The first word can vary in length. An example would be "abc Company" and I want to only capitalize the "abc" and leave the rest as is. How do I do that in SQL Server?

Comment: Find the index of the first occurrence of a space (see CHARINDEX) and then split the string by that space using LEFT / RIGHT. Then concatenate those 2 parts but apply UPPER to the left function. Give it a shot and come back if you get stuck.

Comment: You should also be very clear - are you just looking for this specific example? Which might only apply to a single row? Or do you want to generalize it further?

Comment: Yes you are right I should have been more specific about my question and the other possible scenarios. Either way, thank you for the help it was much appreciated and I figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution I came up with:

```
concat(upper(left(companyname, charindex(' ',companyname)-1)),' ',substring(companyname,CHARINDEX(' ',companyname)+1,Len(companyname))) as fullname
```

Comment: Just curious, was my answer helpful in getting your solution working?

Comment: Yes, I didn't think about concatenating them.